# Django How to make the condition correct on an HTML page - search bar

Tags: html, django

I try to do a search engine if the word in my DB thah I created then display the word on the HTML page and if not then nothing.. I did it right in VIEW but I can not apply it on the HTML page I searched the internet and did not find an answer I'm sure I fall for something stupid.

This is the view

```
def Search_word(request):
search = request.POST.get("search")  #Grab the search item
return render(request,"search_page.html", {"search":search})
```

this is the html:

{%for i in Word.English_word%}

{%if search in Word.English_word%}

{{search}}

{%endif%}
{%endfor%}

and the urls:

```
    path("Search_page",views.Search_word ,name="Search-page"),
```

models:

```
class Words(models.Model):
English_word = models.CharField(max_length=30)
Hebrew_word = models.CharField(max_length=30)
How_To_Remember = models.CharField(max_length=40)
Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

The problem is that even if the word is valid it does not show me anything ..

Comment: What is `Word.English_word` supposed to do?

Comment: It is field from the DB  that contain English_word and Hebrew_word that the user can add the word and the translate of the word. if the word in english exist in the DB I want to display the word for the user and he search for the word .

Comment: can you share the `Word` model. This filtering logic does *not* belong in the template, but in the view. Since this is a search, this is normally done through a GET request.

Comment: Ok  I'll add .I think I did not write the condition correctly on the HTML page

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: I edited now ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the filtering logic in the *view*, not in the template. Templates are for *rendering* logic, not *business logic*. Furthermore one should filter with the database, since databases are designed to do this.

The view thus looks like:

```
def Search_word(request):
    search = request.POST.get('search')
    items = Word.objects.filter(English_word__contains=search)
    return render(
        request,
        'search_page.html',
        {'search': search, 'items': items}
    )
```

and then in the template we render this with:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.English_word }}: {{ item.Hebrew_word }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

You can use as lookup `__contains` to check if the `English_word` has a substring that is equal to `search`, with `__icontains` you check case-insensitive, with `__iexact` you look for `Word`s that match `search` case-insensitive, and finally you can filter with `Engish_word=search` for an exact match.

Comment: Thank you !
Two more questions how can I within the VIEWS
Take out the ID of the word in English and the corresponding word in Hebrew?

Comment: @YoavLavie: if you are only interested in the hebrew word(s), you can use `items = Word.objects.filter(English_word__contains=search).values_list('Hebrew_word', flat=True)`

Comment: But usually it is a bad idea to work with "primitive" types directly: this is often considered an anti-pattern, so normally one passes a queryset of `Item` objects.

Comment: @YoavLavie: but we here pass the items to the `render` call (so `{ 'items': items }`. In the template we enumerate over the match(es) with `{% for item in items %}...{% endfor %}` to show these words. So if an English word matches, then normally that should be sufficient to render this.